# Rate limiting on Next.js application hosted on AWS using AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-ecs, rate-limiting, amazon-waf

I have a frontend Next.js application hosted in AWS ECS, I need to setup Rate limiting on WAF, On networks tab i have 125 requests on each reload, similarly I have 15-20 pages with those many requests on each page load. So,
how do i benchmark that number?
How usually rate-limiting works for frontend applications?
At a time there are around 500 unique users using my site. Please help me benchmark that rate-limiting number for 5mins.